# F# using FSharp.Data not able to get basicAuth working

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am new to F# and trying to automate APIs using FSharp.Data but I am not able to get basic auth working. I know there is some syntax issue that I am not able to crack. Please suggest how to get rid of this error on the "(BasicAuth "username_api" "pwd_api")" part of the code: This expression was expected to have type    'string'    but here has type    'string * string'.

Also, I have attached an image for the quick reference.

Here is my test:

```
[<Test>]
let getBasicAuthUsingData () =
        let Authorization (credentials:string) = "Authorization", credentials

        let BasicAuth (username:string) (password:string) =
            let base64Encode (s:string) =
                let bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
                Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
            sprintf "%s:%s" username password |> base64Encode |> sprintf "Basic %s" |>  Authorization

        let apiURL = "http://sampleapi"


        let response = Http.RequestString( apiURL, httpMethod = "GET", headers = [ "Authorization", (BasicAuth "username_api" "pwd_api")])  
        printfn "Response of get is %s: " response
```

[image: See error:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the name of the header twice: first in the `Authorization` function, and then in the list of headers for some reason.

As a result, the element of the header list ends up being `("Authorization", ("Authorization", "user:pass"))` instead of just `("Authorization", "user:pass")`

Just get rid is one of the `"Authorization"` strings:

```
let response = Http.RequestString( apiURL, httpMethod = "GET", headers = [BasicAuth "username_api" "pwd_api"])
```